# HEROKU: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, backend

I'm getting this error in production when my app is rebooting after a push. It started happening after I added the worker to my Procfile.

`web: node server.js
 worker: node bin/jobWorker/`

My express server is as such:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res
        .status(200)
        .render('index', {
            build: isDev ? null : '/build',
        });
});

server
    .listen(
        Config.port,
        Config.env !== 'production' ? Config.host : null,
        (err) => logServerConfig(err)
    );
```

Any ideas why this error is showing up? I've looked around for answers and none of the solutions applied to this scenario. Most have said to not enter a static port, which is not what I'm doing. I grab the port from `process.env.PORT` where Heroku populates it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I grab the port from process.env.PORT where Heroku populates it." How do you do this?

Comment: @Chris heroku does it automatically because it is running the environment, so the ```process.env.PORT``` will have the port number

Comment: I know the environment variable gets set. I'm asking how _you_ get the environment variable into your application. The code you shared uses `Config.port`; how does `Config.port` get set? Since Heroku is complaining that you're not binding to `$PORT` it's unlikely that you're using this variable correctly.

Comment: @Chris I set it in my config file as such:
```const Config = {  port: process.env.PORT }```

Comment: @Chris this problem started happening after I added a worker process